# What is com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper

Tags: audio, macos

I'm trying to troubleshoot speech recognition dodginess.

Executing `ps -ax | grep audio` I get:

```
ps -ax | grep audio
  130 ??         2:40.49 /usr/sbin/coreaudiod
  166 ??         0:00.02 /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper
  168 ??         0:00.47 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.audio.DriverHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.audio.DriverHelper
 1931 ??         0:00.02 /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper
 1949 ttys001    0:00.00 grep audio
```

What is `com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper`?  Why would I need one, let alone two?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question directly, but wanted to say that I have the exact same 4 processes running on my machine, including the two `SandboxHelper` instances. Therefore, I'm not sure  these processes are relevant to the issue you are having.

Comment: I regularly have over 10 of these processes.

Comment: These are totally legitimate processes. If I can get a reproducible test case, I’ll see if I can debug the XPC or what process spawns them so everyone can determine which app is calling for them. With that low CPU it wouldn’t be a problem to have 50 or more running in most cases, though.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I've been looking at an audio issue today and noticed I had 6 different instances of `com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper` running. Checking showed that the system thinks it has 6 different audio devices attached, so it seems each audio device get a `SandboxHelper` to look after it.

Oddly, no other piece of hardware, or associated drivers, has a `SandboxHelper` associated with it, so either the audio devices are the only ones that need help operating in a Sandbox, or only the audio driver team used that name and other tasks running in Sandboxes have their helpers called something else.

Comment: I routinely have 15 to 20 instances of SandboxHelper running. WTF?

Comment: I currently have many more of these processes than the number of audio devices.

Comment: Could it be virtual audio devices?